# How to determine the 'owning package' of code in virtualenv's site-packages?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm wondering if its possible to determine the ownership of the contents in `<VIRTUAL_ENV_ROOT>/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.

In some cases it is obvious: The package/subfolder `numpy` is (most likely) owned by the package `numpy` on PyPI.

But what if there is a `weirdly_named` package/subfolder where it isn't obvious, i.e., which doesn't correspond to a package on PyPI with the same name? Is there a way to determine which installed package has created a particular sub path?

Basically I'm looking for the `pip` equivalent of `dpkg -S` which can e.g. tell me that the file `/etc/X11/Xsession` is owned by the apt package `x11-common`.

Comment: "*I'm looking for the pip equivalent of…*" There is no one. You cannot do that with `pip` alone.

Comment: @phd: Basically I could take the list installed packages obtained via `pip freeze`, iterate over all packages, install each package in isolation into a temporary virtualenv and collect information on which package has created what. But yeah perhaps you're right and there is nothing more efficient / convenient.

Comment: My original idea was a bit simpler: you don't need to install packages, they're already here. So a loop over `pip list`, for every package `pip show --files | grep -F weirdly_named`.

Comment: @phd Good idea, thanks! I didn't know `pip show --files <package>`, looks promising...

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I'm going for a simple zsh/bash alias:

```sh
alias pip_inspect_ownership='pip show --files $(pip freeze | grep "==" | cut -d "=" -f 1 | tr "\n" " ") | less'
```

The idea is:

- `pip show --files <package> <package> ...` lists all the files owned by each package in the list, separated by a package information header.
- The sub-expression `$(pip freeze | grep "==" | cut -d "=" -f 1 | tr "\n" " ")` filters out packages installed in editable mode, and collects the remaining into a list of all packages.
- I pipe the result through `less` so that I can quickly search for ownership of multiple files.